# Ubuntu not recognizing the primary display

Tags: nvidia, display, brightness

I am using a laptop which has NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti graphics card. I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. However after the installation, as Ubuntu wasn't recognizing the display, the screen resolution was very bad although my laptop has a WLED-backlit (1920 x 1080) screen. Also I wasn't able to adjust the brightness as the brightness section was not all seen anywhere. I was able to fix the screen resolution. But I am not able figure out why the brightness is section is not all appearing. Is there a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With Nvidia  the best results are using the **proprietary drivers** (you can select and install them via the Hardware app, if not already done so)
But that driver doesn't allow you to set the brightness by default. But there is a solution that worked on my thinkpad:

! This will only work with the **proprietary drivers** !

create /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-Nvidia.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Restart. then it should work

#### Update

Since you are a beginner, I'll explain how to do it:
All those things we do, we do in a terminal window. So you need to open the "terminal" app, just like any other program. Inside the terminal you type: (all grey text is what you have to enter). At the end of the gray text you have to press the "enter" or "return" button.
First create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Then open an editor to paste the contents into (just as you did the first time)

```
sudo nano  /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-Nvidia.conf
```

Now you're in a terminal editor. Copy & paste the text from the big gray box into your editor. Use the mouse & context menu to do that.

Now you have to leave the editor. Use Crtl+x (this means: Press the Crtl Key AND the X key together.

Then press "y" on the question  "Save modified buffer?"
To finally leave just press "Return"

You're done.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu. I ran `create /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-Nvidia.conf:` in the terminal. I got the following: " 'create' not found, did you mean:

  command 'pcreate' from deb pbuilder-scripts
  command 'pcreate' from deb python-pyramid."

Can you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: I've extended my answer - see above

Comment: Thank you for the step by step answer. I followed the steps. But when I was returning i.e., the last step (To finally leave just press "Return"), after pressing enter I ended up in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMnpt.png) terminal, which says "Error writing /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-Nvidia.conf: No such file or directory". Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: If it's a long procedure, please never mind.

Comment: Well, you did well, but I've forgotten, that this path is no longer available by default. See my updated instructions above...

Comment: Now with the updated suggestion, I was able to run the code without any errors. After that when I restarted the laptop I ended up in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXwXA.jpg) screen. Even after 10 minutes Ubuntu didn't proceed further from this screen.

Comment: Wow. This is surprising. So I guess, we've got a special situation here. First we need to rollback your change. Next time your start your computer, you need to enter the "grub" menu. For this you should press the "Shift" key while starting until the grub menu is shown: [Grub](https://imgur.com/kr96xO5.png).    Select The "advanced options and start to top most entry with (recovery Mode). You will be prompted with a screen like  [this](https://imgur.com/s3KJuo9.png). Enter the root mode and delete the file with `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-Nvidia.conf`. (You need to know you root password)

Comment: I am using dual boot. I used a USB to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. After the installation of Ubuntu, when Ubuntu was about start supposedly, I ended up in that same black screen (as in the previous comment of mine). Then I uninstalled and tried to install Ubuntu again, but again I ended up in the same black screen. Later one of my friend helped me install Ubuntu, but as said in the question,  the screen resolution was bad indeed. We were able to fix the screen resolution,  but the brightness controller couldn't be enabled.

Comment: BTW  I was not able to rollback the change using `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-Nvidia.conf` as it said no such file or directory.

Comment: Well I said "root". As normal user you can't see that directory. If the 21-Nvidia.conf did not work, then I wonder if you installed the recommended Nvidia driver...

Comment: I entered that piece of code as a root user. I have installed the Nvidia drivers. Rather the screen resolution problem was solved after installing them. But I do not why I am seeing the black screen. Anyways never mind. Thanks for the answer. I will uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it.